# Querying Column Headers in GBQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is it possible to do a query to provide me an output with the column headers of a specific table? I'm uploading multiple files into our server via GBQ and while it auto-detects the headers, I would like to list out the headers either in rows or as a comma separated cell.

Thank you

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your files are in CSV format so schema of table does not have repeated fields. With this in mind - below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and requires just fully qualified table name

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"(.+?)"') cols_as_array,
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"(.+?)"'), ',') cols_as_string
FROM (SELECT 1) LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table` WHERE FALSE) t
ON TRUE
```

If to apply to some real table as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"(.+?)"') cols_as_array,
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"(.+?)"'), ',') cols_as_string
FROM (SELECT 1) LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.us_states_area` WHERE FALSE) t
ON TRUE
```

result will be

```
Row cols_as_array           cols_as_string   
1   region_code             region_code,division_code,state_fips_code,state_gnis_code,state_geo_id,state_abbreviation,state_name,legal_area_code,feature_class_code,functional_status_code,area_land_meters,area_water_meters,internal_point_lat,internal_point_lon,state_geom   
    division_code        
    state_fips_code      
    state_gnis_code      
    state_geo_id         
    state_abbreviation       
    state_name       
    legal_area_code      
    feature_class_code       
    functional_status_code       
    area_land_meters         
    area_water_meters        
    internal_point_lat       
    internal_point_lon       
    state_geom
```

You can choose which version to use: list as array or list as comma separated string

Also note, above query does not incur any cost at all!

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks! Just for curiosity, is it possible to do this within Legacy SQL as well?