# How can I access Schema from the QueryResponse while calling getQueryResults method from my Java application?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using google.cloud.bigquery library to execute and create query using `bigquery.query()` method. I want to fetch the `Schema` details from the response but whenever the query returns no result, I am getting `EmptyTableResult` instead of the response which should have `Schema` and Fields listed inside it. I used another approach which creates job and then using the query job, I am calling `bigquery.getQueryResults` which should return `QueryResponse` object. Below is the code snippet.

```
QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = 
QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(queryString)

.setDefaultDataset(bqDatasetId).setUseLegacySql(false)

 .setFlattenResults(true).build();

JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        Job queryJob = bigQuery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build());

        // Wait for the query to complete.
        queryJob = queryJob.waitFor();

        // Check for errors
        if (queryJob == null) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Job no longer exists");
        } else if (queryJob.getStatus().getError() != null) {
          throw new RuntimeException(queryJob.getStatus().getError().toString());
        }

        // Get the results.
        QueryResponse response = bigQuery.getQueryResults(queryJob.getJobId());
        System.out.println(response);
```

Here, in `sysout` statement, I am getting the proper response, but whenever I am trying to use `response.getSchema()`, it is giving me compilation error saying `getSchema()` is not visible. Can anyone help me with this? Is this approach correct or there is any other approach which can do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, I came to a conclusion that it is better to use reflections to invoke the invisible QueryRespons.getSchema() method and it worked like a charm. Though, reflection is not an ideal solution for this but it has resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `getQueryResults()` on the `Job` object instead. This will give you back a `TableResult` object. You can then call `getSchema()` to get the schema of the query/table/job. So, putting it all together:

```
QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig =
                QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(
                        "SELECT "
                                + "CONCAT('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/', CAST(id as STRING)) as url, "
                                + "view_count "
                                + "FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` "
                                + "WHERE tags like '%google-bigquery%' "
                                + "ORDER BY favorite_count DESC LIMIT 10")
                        .setUseLegacySql(false)
                        .build();

        JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        Job queryJob = BIGQUERY.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build());
        queryJob = queryJob.waitFor();

        TableResult result = queryJob.getQueryResults(); //<--you need this
        Schema schema = result.getSchema(); //<--..and this

        System.out.println(schema);
```

Which yields:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64695', transport: 'socket'
Schema{fields=[Field{name=url, type=STRING, mode=NULLABLE, description=null}, Field{name=view_count, type=INTEGER, mode=NULLABLE, description=null}]}
```

Comment: Hi Graham, Thank you for reverting back. I tried this as well but it is giving me EmptyTableResult. i want to get the schema of the query which do not return any result for now.

Comment: As the API works now, it is supposed to return null if the query comes back empty. As you said in your question, the response itself bears the schema (even if the query returns null), among other things, so you can parse it from there if necessary.

In your code, `response.getSchema()` will not work anymore because that is how it was done in an older version of the library for BigQuery. You can see an example of the former usage [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.cloud.bigquery.QueryResponse), in example 9.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static JSONArray convert(TableResult resultSet) throws Exception {

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    Schema schema = resultSet.getSchema();
    FieldList MyFields = schema.getFields();
    Field MyField2 = null;
    for (FieldValueList row : resultSet.iterateAll()) {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < MyFields.size(); i++) {
            MyField2 = MyFields.get(i);
            obj.put(MyField2.getName().toLowerCase(), row.get(i).getValue());
        }
        jsonArray.put(obj);
    }
    return jsonArray;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another approach is to use the solution in this ticket [Querying Column Headers in GBQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53768914/querying-column-headers-in-gbq/53770554?r=SearchResults#53770554)

This is running a query and not using the api

Comment: I am using api only, not running the query directly. Thanks though :)